# Object range with conditions

Tags: range

In groovy I can write

```
def n = 10
print 1..<n
```

Output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Are there other language that allow to specify range with conditions?

examples

```
def n = 10
print 1<=..n
```

Output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

```
def n = -2
print 1<=..n
```

Output: [1]

```
def n = -2
print 1..n
```

Output: [1, 0, -1, -2]

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what your question is (i.e. what answers you're expecting).

Comment: I search language where this is implemented

Comment: functional languages usually have it, through the use of some function. example (Haskell): `filter (< 10) [1..]` (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

Answer (score 0):

Python has the [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) method which does a similar thing. While it does not use operators for the condition you can specify a start value, stop value and step value. It then creates a list containing all values starting with the start value, then start+step, ... until it reaches the end value (which is not included).